# Java error "possible loss of precision"

Tags: java

I am in a computer science class (11th) for hw i have to do some code following a picture
--------------------Configuration: --------------------

```
C:\Users\I_SLAY_NOOBS\Desktop\Variables.java:26: error: possible loss of precision
        float floatOne = 58.5678;
                         ^
  required: float
  found:    double
1 error
```

Process completed.

Comment: *THIS IS THE CODE*
//integer variables
  byte byteOne = 127;
  short shortOne = -32123;
  int intOne = 90877;
  long longOne = 999999999;


  //decimal variables
     double doubleOne = 923.234;
     float floatOne = 58.5678;

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 2):

You assign a `double` which is more precise than a `float` to a variable declared as `float`. Float values end with an **f** in Java. Plain floating point numbers are automatically considered to be doubles...

Either do:

```
float f = 58.5678f;
```

or:

```
double d = 58.5678;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *truly* want a `float` (single precision IEEE754), you can use:

```
float floatOne = 58.5678f;
```

Me, I'd simply go with the `double` type everywhere since it provides more precision than `float`:

```
double doubleOne = 58.5678;
```

The default for floating point constants in Java (and C and C++, among others) is double precision and you're trying to shoehorn that into a single-precision variable, hence the message. Appending `f` to a floating point constant tells the compiler that you *want* it to be single precision.

Unless you have vast arrays of them (and limited space to store them), doubles are generally preferred.

Comment: Added like you said and it worked, Thank you so much!